# Question about comparator MAX912 latch enable

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, pulldown

http://www.hep.uiuc.edu/cleo/trig3/boards/tile/vme021d_data_sheets/max912.pdf

I am using this MAX912 as comparator. There is a latch enable in this circuit which according to the datasheet, output is latched when LEA is TTL high or floating and latch is transparent when LEA is low.
I have two questions about this latch.
1. I am using a pull down resister and connecting Q- to latch enable (LEA).  Output Q is high (initial state) until input state changes. Q- will change from low to high and enable the latch. Can this circuit serves as a one time voltage detector? I only want it be triggered once.
[image: MAX912]

2. This chip is in TTL logic. Someone mentioned that there is a current limit for logical low for TTL. What value should I use for this pull down resister?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're showing here will work in theory.

However, a high on the latch input takes a few nanoseconds to take effect, and the input should be stable during this time.

These two effects will let you miss very short voltage spikes.

Another thing to consider is the start-up time. If you put the circuit as it on a board and power it up, the voltages at the input and the supply voltage will not instantly be applied but ramp up slowly.

What happends during this period is pretty much undefined. Your comparator may trigger and instantly lock up. So you'll likely want some kind of switch that lets you reset the latch once it's locked. This requires a few parts around the comparator.

In the end it may be cheaper and more practical to ignore the latch feature and use a simple RS flip-flop. The S-pin goes to your comparator output and the R-pin could be connected to a power-on reset chip such as the LP3470 or so.

For the pulldown: The datasheet does not directly specify the current capabilities of the output, but they give figures for 10mA, so this current is safe. The lowest pulldown would be VSuppy / 10mA. For 5V that would be 500 Ohm. I'd just stick a 10k resistor there however. No need to burn so much current just for a pulldown.